# With respect to ReactJS + Webpack, how can I include local images in my site?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a site, that I'm trying to re-make into a react edition.

http://matiny.altervista.org/VI/

If I'm not mistaken, I would have to use online links for all my images (as opposed to local paths). There's only 1 small problem: On just the front page, I have 40 images. Is there a headache-free way to include these images locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use local paths for your images with webpack. Check the guide [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images)

Comment: Thanks, I've been having trouble finding a comprehensive tutorial on using React and the associated tech.